# Blazemeter: How to read error JTL file of Blazemeter?

Tags: excel, jmeter, report, excel-2010, blazemeter

I want to read the **error.jtl** file which we get from *Blazemeter Logs (File name- Artifacts).*
I am currently using Excel to read the file. Is there any other way, I can view this JTL file, in the same manner, we see the JMeter results jtl file(to HTML Report)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error.jtl` is a JMeter-specific file which is generated by [Taurus framework](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ArtifactsDir/), it contains request and response data for the samplers which have failed during the test execution.

I don't know what do you mean by "read", the file is normal XML file so you can use any text or XML viewer/editor to inspect it.

Also as per [How to Capture Response Data from a JMeter JTL File (NTC)](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000671818-How-to-Capture-Response-Data-from-a-JMeter-JTL-File-NTC-) article:

> Unzip artifacts.zip and open the trace.jtl / error.jtl in JMeter's [View Results Tree Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-1-basic-display-formats). The samplers are listed. When selected, the response data can be examined.

so you can open it in [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) or any other [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice.

You cannot generate HTML Reporting Dashboard from the .jtl file in XML format, however you can use i.e. [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to extract only failing sample results from the `kpi.jtl` file and generate the dashboard out of it.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Your suggestions helped.
By "read", I meant I wanted to read it in a better way. For large XMLs, it is difficult to read in an XML viewer. But, now with Listeners, I am good.
Thanks again!